# Using PImpl Idiom and Curiously Recurring Template Pattern

Tags: c++, boost-gil

I'm getting some compiling errors when creating constructors for my derived image classes while using PImpl Idiom and Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. The base class for image class implementations uses CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) to enforce static dispatch instead of layering on another virtual call. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Please see the comments for where the errors occur

// Error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'jpeg_image::impl' [clang-diagnostic-error]

// Error: field has incomplete type 'jpeg_image::impl' [clang-diagnostic-error]

image.hpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace image_wrapper {
 
    class image {
    public:
       //ToDo: declare pure virtual functions
    };

    class jpeg_image final : public image {
        class impl;
        std::unique_ptr<impl> _impl;

    public:
        // Destructor and constructor for reading from a buffer of encoded_bytes
        ~jpeg_image();
        jpeg_image(std::vector<uint8_t> encoded_bytes);
    };
} //namespace image_wrapper
```

image.cpp

```
#include "image.hpp"
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <functional>

namespace image_wrapper {
    namespace {

        template <class Derived>
        class impl_base {
        public:
            // ToDo: implement base class functions
        protected:
            // Constructor
            explicit impl_base(std::vector<uint8_t> encoded_bytes) :
                _unencoded_image{ std::bind(&impl_base<Derived>::initialize_unencoded_image, this) }, _encoded_bytes{ encoded_bytes }
            {
            }

        private:
            boost::gil::rgb8_image_t initialize_unencoded_image() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).decode_bytes(); }
            boost::gil::rgb8_image_t _unencoded_image;
            std::vector<uint8_t> _encoded_bytes;
        };
    } // namespace

    /*
     * JPEG Class Definitions
     */
    class jpeg_image::impl : public impl_base<jpeg_image::impl> {
    public:

        // Error: field has incomplete type 'jpeg_image::impl'
        jpeg_image::impl(std::vector<uint8_t> encoded_bytes) : impl_base<jpeg_image::impl>(encoded_bytes) {}

        boost::gil::rgb8_image_t decode_bytes()
        {
         // ToDo: implement decode_bytes()
        }
    };

    // Error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'jpeg_image::impl' [clang-diagnostic-error]
    jpeg_image::jpeg_image(std::vector<uint8_t> encoded_bytes) : _impl(new jpeg_image::impl(encoded_bytes)) {}

    // Jpeg Image Destructor
    jpeg_image::~jpeg_image() = default;

} // namespace image_wrapper
```

Comment: What are the errors it produces and have you reduced this down to an [MCVE]?

Comment: Hello, I've just tried to reduce this down to a minimal reproducible example. Please see the comments for where the errors occur

Comment: That can not be *minimal* example. I would start with removing all references to boost, extra STL headers, unused functions, etc.

Comment: I've reduced the code as much as possible. I still need the boost::gil stuff to demonstrate what I'm trying to do

Comment: Your `jpeg_image::impl` constructor should be named `impl` *not* `jpeg_image::impl`.